# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Tenho uma tabela funcionário e endereço. A endereço está recendo uma chave estrangeira da funcionário, porém, está dando o seguinte erro quando vou inserir:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Como resolvo isso?

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO ENDERECO (FUNCIONARIO_FUN_CODIGO) 
    VALUES(:codigoFuncionario)";

    try{
        $resultado=$db_con->prepare($consulta);

        //$resultado->BindParam(':cep',$cep,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $resultado->BindParam(':codigoFuncionario',$codigoFuncionario,PDO::PARAM_STR);


        $resultado->execute();
```

Comment: Só com a mensagem de erro fica difícil ajudar, poste seus códigos

Comment: Esse `FUNCIONARIO_FUN_CODIGO` pelo que entendi faz referencia para outra tabela, correto? Verifique se o que esta inserindo nesse valor existe nessa outra tabela a qual referencia.

Comment: Sim, eu verifiquei e existe

Comment: De onde está vindo esta variável $codigoFuncionario?
Verificou se ela está sendo setada corretamente e com um valor existente no banco de dados?

Comment: Outro detalhe, o que o @MarceloBoni comentou está corretíssimo, o erro diz que a informação que está sendo inserida na tabela endereço não existe na outra tabela, verifique estes itens.

Comment: Verifica se você não definiu FUNCIONARIO_FUN_CODIGO como auto-increment